# java null pointer exception while configuring axis2 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, apache-axis

I am trying to implement web services using axis2, in Eclipse. (I had downloaded axis2-1.5 runtime and created environment variable for it.) I had created a dynamic web project and set the axis2 runtime successfully in Axis2 preferences.

After creating the project, I tried setting the project facet, but end up getting the following error: Failed while installing Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1

Stack shows only:NullPointerException(which is not helping me much in understanding the problem). Wat could be the problem? Without this, it's difficult to test web services using axis2.

Comment: We can't do much without seeing the stacktrace.

Comment: StackTrace shows only java null pointer exception.

Comment: And it should show *where* it occured. Or, if you can't see more on the console view, there should be additional info in the eclipse logs. Your eclipse IDE, is it the latest stable build?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is quite well documented on the eclipse forums. It seems to be related to the older versions of axis2.

Some people suspect, that it is related to the workspace configuration. There is one advise that sounds promising:

> I found the solution for this problem. After conf. the apache tomcat and Axis2 just create new workspace and the error will not be occur again.

**Further Reading:**

- [Thread on eclipse community forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/62333/)

Comment: I was getting the nullpointerexception as above and creating the Dynamic Web Project with Axis2 in a new workspace sorted the error.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download binary description of `Axis2` , then download  `Axis_war` then  **copy** the contents of `Axis_war` to `Axis2` binary description folder. Then select the preference on eclipse the binary direction folder.

That’s all.

Answer (score 0):

Just Update the java to 1.7 and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I also experience heap size errors and fixed it by changing the following line in my eclipse.ini

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

```
to
```

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

in other words, I increased the initial heap size.

I also changed the vm parameter to the bin subdirectory of the selected jre version under Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE's > Location

Not sure which change fixed it. but it works now.